# How faster show multicursors on the end of all lines?

Tags: region, multiple-cursors

Som teext

```
1111111111
2
33333
4444444444444
5555 9999
6666   aaaa
aaaaaa
zzzzzzzzz
hello
prev
do this
```

My steps:

1. Put cursor to the beginning of first line (1111111111)

[image]

2. Press `C-> (mc/mark-next-like-this)` 10 times.
   [image]
3. Press `End`

[image]

Nice. It's work.

But is it possible to do this faster? Without 3 steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `mc/edit-ends-of-lines` adds a cursor to the end of the every line in the region. There are many ways to set the region. If you want to mark every line in a file, you can set the region to the whole file with `C-x h`.

It's very helpful to spend a few minutes reading the documentation for multiple cursors, which includes a list of all the different ways to add cursors, one at a time and in large numbers: https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el